# Multiple resultsets in Elasticsearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch, drupal, drupal-8

I have an application build with PHP + elasticsearh and I have a search page where articles are shown with a list of filters, I need to have a default view respecting some filter.

In elasticsearch I need to make a complicated search, in the top of my results I need to have results for specific filters (articles with price under 10$) then I need to have other results which respect some other filters (articles having at least a picture) then other results.

I hope my case is clear.

best regards

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: You have to make a filtered query , use ElasticClient to build your own request